# error in making a layout in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which I have to make a layout.I have tried lot of things like creating sliding drawer,custom list,,etc.But i am finding difficulty in making a layout .

The image is

[freeimagehosting.net/a32ae](http://freeimagehosting.net/a32ae)

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android’s SlidingDrawer is a pretty neat & handy component. It does what its supposed to open/close a drawer revealing with it tucked away icons or additional view components.

-Intuitive use of a well-known archetype everybody knows: a drawer which open/close..simple!

-Saves and maximizes use of screen real estate

-Visually appealing.

[Check this example](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b49a47h/n/TestSlidingDrawerOverList.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Have a llok on the following tutorial to get some idea regarding designing layout and custom list view

See [How to create a layout](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-development-ui-layouts.html)

Also

[How to create custom list view](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

or

[custom list view](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)